# Something in canvas disappear unexcepted when focus another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, canvas

My code is like this:

```js
(function() {
 var c = $('#board')[0].getContext('2d');
 $('#board').click(_tst);
 var _tst_idx = 0;
 function _tst(e) {
  c.fillRect(40 + (_tst_idx++) * 50, 40, 40, 40);
 }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="board" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u063s0s4/

Just click the canvas and draw a box on it.
But, when I focus another window, the 2nd box disappear unexpected.
Like this: http://i2.tietuku.com/8398bd6aacc39e5d.png

I used Chrome 39.0.2171.95/Win 7, I don't know what's wrong with this code.

Thanks.

============ more ==================

I have tried to use the stealth mode of chrome or disable all extensions, the 2nd box was still disappeared.
But the code works all right on the other computer of mine.
That's so strange!

Only the 2nd rendering to canvas will disappear.
So I used this code on init to avoid it:

```
(function(a,b){
    a(function(){
        b(0, 0, 1, 1);
        a(function(){
            b(0, 0, 1, 1);
        });
    });
})(requestAnimationFrame, c.clearRect.bind(c));
```

=============== more =============

When I disabled "Use hardware acceleration when available" in the chrome setting, it became fine.
My GPU: NVIDIA 560TI

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Chrome 39.0.2171.95, and it sounds really strange.

Comment: Also can't reproduce

Comment: Ditto, all rects remain in Win8.1/Chrome39.0.2171.95 -- no disappearing.

Comment: Might not be a "code" issue. Can't reproduce either on FF 35, 37, opera 26, chrome 39 on osX 10.9.